# Setting ServerName to suppress Apache warning message with multiple domains

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

When I restart/reload/whatever apache2 (2.4) on Ubuntu Server 14.10, I get the error message that the server could not determine the FQDN. I had this set previously, no big deal, but I now have two domain names on the server managed by separate VirtualHost config files. What should I set ServerName to in `apache2.conf` to suppress the error since I have multiple domain names? Should it globally be the server's IP address but set individually in the VirtualHost configs the proper way?

Comment: Just set it to localhost.

Comment: @cuonglm Well, that's simple, I didn't even think about that. If you post as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set it to `localhost`. Edit `/etc/apache2/conf.d/httpd.conf`:

```
ServerName localhost
```

The [ServerName directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) can be use in two contexts: `server config` or `virtual host`.

- In `server config` context, `ServerName` directive is used when creating redirection URLs.
- In `virtual host` context, `ServerName` directive is used to uniquely identify a virtual host.

So you must set `ServerName` inside a [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) section for each domain configuration to identify two domains. The global value will make the warning message disappear and doesn't affect the identity between two domains.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, which ServerName you choose globally, any will suppress that warning.

Just add a line to your fully qualified hostname to the apache configuration:

```
LINE='ServerName www.example.com'
FILE='/etc/apache2/apache2.conf'
grep -qF -- "$LINE" "$FILE" || echo "$LINE" >> "$FILE"
service apache2 restart
```

If your main server has no domain, use `localhost` instead.

If you really care about those multiple domains, set them inside each VirtualHost section for each domain configuration.

Answer (score -1):

In CentOS 7x the file is located at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.